# Is there a way to prevent usage of unimplemented functions during compile time?

Tags: c++, compile-time

often I encounter hacks like

```
//lets say this is some class that still doesnt support...
//...all the functionality that it should based on the design docs
void MyClass::MyFunction()
{
  throw std::exception("not implemented");
}
```

I guess this is a bad practice, but that aside:
Is there a way to do the same thing during compilation, but only if the function is used (aka if it is unused compile should succeed).

Edit: Im also interested in virtual mem functions.

Comment: If a function is _not implemented_ (as in, not declared but not defined) then you will get a link time error.  In this case, your function is implemented, and has well defined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is non-virtual function then you can simply comment out the definition.

If it is a virtual function declared in a base class, then you can't control the calls at compile time, so then your only option is some run-time error or exception.

Answer (score 6):

If you remove the implementation entirely and only have the function declaration, there will be a linker error, which is basically compile time. Unfortunately, linker errors have a tendency to be ugly and hard to track down, but in the case of calling a function that hasn't been implemented yet I think they're pretty manageable.

Comment: Linker error is not *basically* compile-time. It is link-time.

Comment: What if the function is virtual and some base class has implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but still...

I use a couple of simple helper for this. It'll give an error link-time that's fairly readable:

```
// Not implemented is not implemented :-)thing, it'll break:
struct NotImplHelper { static void notimplemented(); };
#define notimplemented() NotImplHelper::notimplemented();
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
#define notimplementedvirtual() throw std::exception();
#else
#define notimplementedvirtual() static_assert(false, "You should implement virtual function calls before moving to production.");
#endif
```

Usage:

```
//lets say this is some class that still doesnt support...
//...all the functionality that it should based on the design docs
void MyClass::MyFunction()
{
    notimplemented();
    // or notimplementedvirtual() if MyFunction() is virtual... 
}
```

**Rationale:**

IMHO if you use a function in your program, it should be available. When you try to compile something that you haven't implemented yet, it should give a compile-time or link-time error.

F.ex., in MSVC++ this'll give:

```
1>Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl NotImplHelper::notimplemented(void)" (?notimplemented@NotImplHelper@@SAXXZ) referenced in function "[blahblahblah]"
```

Note that the 'referenced function' is there in MSVC++. I haven't tested it in other compilers.

As for not-implemented virtual function calls, the only option you have it to throw an exception. Not having these implemented in your debugger while developing is fine - however, the moment stuff gets serious, these might be called by your program, so they should be available. A `static_assert` ensures the latter. (So: combined with any continuous integration package, it'll basically fail.)

Obviously most people will accidentally mix up `notimplemented` and `notimplementedvirtual`. In reality this ain't a big problem: a simple solution is to always use the former, unless you want to get rid of the error because it's a WIP.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to comment the unimplemented function.

Maybe not what you had in mind, but doing so will generate a compile-time error if anything tries to use it, and the resulting code should be identical to an empty function, which is usually optimized away.